# Convert character column in data frame to date

Tags: r

I have a data frame, with a column of type "character". It is formatted like:
"2017-12-18 17:35:53"

I wish to convert this to a date format. I believed the following code would have worked, but it hasn't:

```
library(magrittr)

df1 %<>% mutate(responded_at= as.Date(column_name, format = "%d.%m.%Y"))
```

I'm not sure what else to try (I'm quite new to R).

Comment: The `format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`  also, it is the default format, so you should good to use `as.Date(column_name)` i.e. `as.Date("2017-12-18 17:35:53")#
[1] "2017-12-18"`

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `"%d.%m.%Y"` implies two digit day followed by a dot (`.`), then two digit month, followed by dot (`.`) and a four digit year (`%Y` - 4 digit year, `%y` - 2 digit year).  Based on the format of the data, it is 4 digit year followed by a dash `-`, then two digit month, dash and two digit day followed by space and hour, minute, seconds in %H:%M:%S format.  So, if we follow the correct format, it would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df1 %<>% 
 mutate(responded_at= as.Date(column_name, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Fortunately, this format is also the default format for `POSIXct`.  So, we can directly use `as.Date` without any `format`

```
df1 %<>% 
       mutate(responded_at= as.Date(column_name))
```